# Wait while file load in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How I can load and return file from another method(use `WWW`)?
I want to do next:

1. Method `GetSettings()`. Download file text, parse json and
   return result.
2. Call method from `Start()` and wait while `GetSettings()` return result.

How I can do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to receive the contents of a file as a static method. How to make such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to downloaded data then wait then wait for the download to finish then download another data. If this is true the you can the code below will download data 2 times. You can increase the number of times by increasing the `REQ_AMOUNT` value.

It uses `yield return StartCoroutine` to wait for the current coroutine function to return before running again.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{

    int REQ_AMOUNT = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < REQ_AMOUNT; i++)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(GetSettings());
    }
}

IEnumerator GetSettings()
{
    string url = RoomSettings.AbsoluteFilenamePath;

    if (Application.isEditor)
    {
        url = "file:///" + url;
    }

    var www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    // Do some code, when file loaded
}
```

Comment: 'yield return StartCoroutine(GetSettings()); Debug.log("ok");'
Debug.Log() call after downloading file in GetSettings()?

Comment: GetSettings() will be called again after it finish running.